# HorizontalScrollView overscroll & parent view

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontalscrollview, android-overscoll

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` that user can scroll to read a number of `TextViews`.
This is placed inside a `ViewPager`.

So, if user scrolls the entire `HorizontalScrollView` instead of showing the overscroll, I want that the entire page (inside `ViewPager`) start scrolling...

Any idea?

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:id="@+id/tagLine"
    >
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

LinearLayout is filled at runtime with `TextView`

This layout is inflated by a `Fragment` used by a `ViewPager`